# why can't my windows phone lumia 640 connect to a Wi-FI?

Tags: wifi

I have a windows phone lumia 640, and I can't connect to WI-Fi at all. I tried to connect to a Wi-Fi but I doesn't let me, it keeps saying "Your phone can't connect to this Wi-Fi". I can sometimes connect when i'm right next to the router but I have to be real close to it. I tried everything. I turn Wi-Fi sense off then back on, that didn't work. I restarted my phone and it still didn't work. I did hard resetting and that still didn't work. Please tell me what  I could do to help this problem.

Comment: What sort of WiFi network is it that you're attempting to connect to? (802.11g? 802.11n? etc.)

Comment: I've had this issue with my 730, heard it's a firmware problem. Resetting the router however did make it work, and rebooting the phone too.
Now i'm on WP10 and didn't experience such problem, YET.